# how to customize table of content for Beamer output in markdown?

Tags: beamer, pandoc

I tried putting the following lines under `header-inludes:` in the YAML header of the markdown.

```
- \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[round]
- \setbeamerfont{section number projected}{size=\large}
- \setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=red,fg=green}
```

That didn't work and it produced this error:

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

What I am aiming is to set custom title and the look of toc.

### This is test markdown document:

```
---
title: Test beamer
date: April 2019
theme: Madrid
aspectratio: 169
header-includes:
  - \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[round] 
  - \setbeamerfont{section number projected}{size=\large}
  - \setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=red,fg=green} 
---

\tableofcontents

# Head 1
## Slide title 1 
Some content

# Head 2
## Slide title 2
Some other content
```

And pandoc command:

```
pandoc -t beamer -o testbeamer.pdf testbeamer.md --slide-level=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc is escaping the square brackets, which is causing the LaTeX error. You can either [add header-includes from the command line or escape the input](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2139). Note that instead of adding `\tableofcontents` to the document, it's better to add `--table-of-contents` to the shell command:

```
---
title: Test beamer
date: April 2019
theme: Madrid
aspectratio: 169
header-includes: |
  `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[round]`{=latex}
  \setbeamerfont{section number projected}{size=\large}
  \setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=red,fg=green} 
---

# Head 1
## Slide title 1 
Some content

# Head 2
## Slide title 2
Some other content
```